# Display SQL Tabe in listbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

at the moment the results from the code below are shown as one list in a single column. How do I amend the code to show each field in a separate column? Many thanks.

```
Private Sub loadSelection()

'Add Params and run query
sql.addParam("@productName", "%" & productSearch.Text & "%")

sql.ExecQuery("SELECT itemName, category, itemID " &
          "FROM Inventory " &
          "WHERE product LIKE @productName;")

    'Report & abort on errors
    If sql.HasException(True) Then Exit Sub

    'loop rows and return users to the list
    For Each r As DataRow In sql.DBDataTable.Rows
         listBox1.Items.Add(r("itemName"))
         listBox1.Items.Add(r("category"))
         listBox1.Items.Add(r("itemID"))
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You could use the listview control, in detail mode to give you columns.  Otherwise, bind the data table to a data grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using a `ListBox` or a `ListView`. You should be using a `DataGridView` control and binding via a `BindingSource`. Add both to your form in the designer and then do this:

```vb
myBindingSource.DataSource = sql.DBDataTable
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource
```

That will, by default, create the columns in the grid automatically at run time. If you need something other than the default behaviour, you can create the columns yourself at run time and set their `DataPropertyName` to make them bind to a specific data source column.

Also note that this creates a live relationship between the `DataTable` and the grid. That means that you must not repurpose that same `DataTable` for some other data while it's bound to that grid. I've seen others do just that when using a DAL like you appear to have created. I've many such DAL implemented with the best of intentions but the result is poor.

Comment: @pete-s I have done what you have both suggested thank you. Using the DatagridView is much easier.

Comment: @Matt, I agree.  I suggested it in my original comment and it's the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Using List View**

Here is one option with the [list view control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=netframework-4.8):

```
 Dim listItem As ListViewItem = Form.lvwListCtl.Items.Add(r("itemID"))

 listItem.SubItems.Add(r("itemName"))
 listItem.SubItems.Add(r("category"))
```

Set the View property to `lvwListCtl.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details`

**Using the List Box**

This is a little "hacky"; but, you could do something like this.  Add one line, and format each field as fixed length, something like this:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(r("itemName").ToString.PadRight(100, " ") & r("category").ToString.PadRight(50, " ") & r("itemID").ToString.PadRight(10, " ")
```

Note: Either option you need to handle NULL values returned.

Comment: While a `ListView` is not wrong per se, it is not a grid control and should not be used as such, even though many people abuse it in that way. If you're not using multiple views or grouping in the `ListView`, you almost certainly should not be using it at all.

Comment: Rather than `listBox1.Items.Add(r("itemName").ToString.PadRight(100, " ") & r("category").ToString.PadRight(50, " ") & r("itemID").ToString.PadRight(10, " ")`, you should actually use `listBox1.Items.Add($"{r("itemName"), -100}{r("category"), -50}{r("itemID"), -10}"`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I agree, a DataGrid control would be better.  That was my original comment as well.